# Pokemon CP vs HP

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it better to evolve Pokemon with higher CP or HP? Also would you power up the higher HP's CP before or after you evolve them?

Answer (score 2):

Each Pokémon has a certain CP and HP but there are more underlying factors that matter, which combine into a single number called IV. You'll be looking to evolve your Pokémons which have the highest IV, as explained in multiple articles including one from [EuroGamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-23-pokemon-go-cp-meaning-explained-how-to-get-the-highest-cp-values-and-create-the-most-powerful-team):

> CP, or Combat Points, is a measure of how strong your Pokémon will be in battle against another Pokémon, and is actually a combination of several hidden stats. Each Pokémon in Pokémon Go has a set of Base Stats for Attack, Defence, and Stamina, along with a hidden Level and a hidden modifier for those Base Stats, known as a Pokémon's IVs.

HP is also one of those factors which is a result of the previously mentioned stats. It is true that higher HP can be an indicator for better IV but if the powering up cost is too high and the CP is so much higher than the other Pokémon you're comparing him with it doesn't give you the right idea.

Using an [IV Calculator](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator) will help you determine which ones of your Pokémons is individually the strongest and will become the strongest one after powering up completely after evolving.

I'm not going into more details right here as there have been written a lot of articles and answers related to this topic and it should be relatively easy to learn more from here.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes HP is higher in a Pokemon with lower CP, so to claim the higher CP always has higher HP is false.

Right now I can evolve a growlithe and have kept two:
One is CP 861/HP 74 and one is CP 814/HP 79

This lower CP has better HP and also a better moveset:
(I know moveset will change, so this is not so important)

So it seems like a better choice may be to evolve 
the lower CP Growlithe, which should remain a higher HP Arcanine post-evolution and also have more room for further power-up post-evolution, since it is slightly lower on the arc.

Can someone give an opinion as to whether my logic is correct, or if I am missing something?

My guess is perhaps the higher CP Growlithe has some unseen attributes that make its CP higher, but I question the real practical benefit of these unknowns in a gym battle.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, evolve a Pokemon with higher CP that has a better IVs (evaluate it though Appraisal).

Comment: Downvoter, please care to explain why you downvoted the answer.

Comment: The first statement is clearly not true and may misinform the asker. If you check Pokémon performance statistics, you will see that high Attack, low HP/defense Pokémon do pretty badly in both attacking and defending gyms.

Comment: If you can't stay alive you can't do dmg, you can't dodge everything.

Comment: @0x0000eWan The question asks, "is it better to evolve higher HP or CP pokemons" and the answer mentions that CP should be considered first rather than the HP while evolving a Pokemon. Since the ratio of CP/HP is always directly proportional (in most cases), the Pokemon with less CP would always have lesser HP.

Comment: @ParasShah While this is true, it doesn't explain why you have included this statement "HP shouldn't matter, as attacking is more important in the game. To avoid damage, you've the option of dodging the moves." which is obviously not correct, in your answer. The rest is ok.